# After the Lavabit shutdown: Download of mails? Forwarding address?

Tags: email, backup

In an [interview with CNET News](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1009_3-57597954-83/lavabit-chief-predicts-long-fight-with-feds-q-a/), Ladar Levison (founder of [Lavabit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavabit)) answered to the question **What happens to your customer's e-mails and data?**:

> I'm looking into setting up a site where users can download their data and set up a forwarding [e-mail] address, but that may take a week or two to set up. That's all I can do until I feel confident that I can resume the service without having to compromise its integrity.
>
> I will make it clear that I don't plan to use any encryption for that site. [People] should only use it if they feel comfortable with the information being intercepted. And yes, I do plan to have that disclaimer on the site.

Whether for setting up a forwarding address for new incoming mails, or whether for downloading all online saved mails, or for both:

Is there such a site? If not, will there be one?

Comment: Follow-up question on Security SE: [Can we make sure that the new Lavabit certificate is not under control of the FBI?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/43924/12139)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lavabit has announced users will be able to access their emails. Access will be available here: https://liberty.lavabit.com/

Right now you can change your password in case you are worried about that being compromised. The ability to download an archive of emails will be available from  Friday, October 18th at 7pm CT.

Comment: Ha, great! Thank you, John C. I asked four days too early ;-) For the record, here is the [press release](http://www.engadget.com/2013/10/14/lavabit-reopens-briefly-ssl-archive/).

Comment: And here is the [announcement from Levison](https://rally.org/lavabit#post_gRdzf0nzD6E) himself.